# Would these lenses fit my future Nikon D7000?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon, camera-recommendation, nikon-d7000

I am in the progress of choosing my new equipment. First of all I have picked the Nikon D7000, it seems like a very nice camera, and it is not that expensive. I could go Full-Frame but seeing the price-tag that might be a little too much, and I would rather like some nice lenses.

Right now I got my eyes on these two:

- Nikon Nikkor AF-S 50mm f/1.4G
- Nikon Nikkor 105mm f/2.8G AF-S VR Micro

I feel this should cover, a lot of the photos I would like to be taking. The 105mm could be replaced with a Nikon Nikkor AF-S DX Micro 85mm f/3.5G ED VR, but I am hearing that the 105mm will give a little extra.

I would like to know, does these lenses fit the Nikon D7000? Would they still be nice if I in some years upgrade to FX?

Would you recommend some other lenses? And in time what lens would you recommend as the third lens.

Also feel free to comment on the choice of the Nikon D7000, I have been looking at cameras like Canon D7, but I feel the Nikon is a little better.

I have used a Canon 450D and a Canon 600D before, also a little bit of Nikon... mostly rented by friends.

Thanks for reading, I hope you got some input!

Comment: Remember that on the crop-sensor D7000 50mm is effectively 75mm -- a bit long. I would want something a bit wider. Nikon has a 35mm f1.8 that is more like the traditional 50mm view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both those lenses are compatible with the D7000 and that should also be the case with any FX camera you buy further down the line. A 50mm lens is an excellent choice for a starter lens, and the 1.4 is an excellent example of one. The 105mm will be very good for portraits, and of course macro photography.

Your choice for a third lens will be determined by what kind of photography you want to do. If you feel you want to try landscape photography, you may want to invest in a wider angle lens. If you want to try wildlife or sports photography, you will want something longer. I would concentrate on learning the camera and photography in general before even thinking about a third lens, however. A good tripod is arguably more important anyway.

The D7000 is by all accounts an excellent camera and is a great choice. Happy photographing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I would wait a little before getting the third. Could you recommend a good tripod? Maybe a flash?

Comment: There's a tripod to suit every budget and need - the same with flashes. Good tripod names are Manfrotto, Giottos, and Gitzo. Cheap tripods are a false economy - you want something with some weight. A good head is also important - I would recommend a ball head. If you can afford them, Nikon flashes are excellent and offer various options for being triggered off-camera, but there are good budget flashguns available from the likes of Metz and Sunpak. It really depends on how much you have to spend, but in general, just get the best you can afford. If you buy cheap, you buy twice!

Comment: Test: Mount camera on tripod. Turn off any stabilisation. Lock focus on distant object with a longish lens - 100mm+ but the more the better. Engage the focus magnifier at maximum setting. Observe image on live view display until it settles. Tap or touch the camera briefly. Watch the display dance wildly to an unbelievable extent, or sit rock solid,  or somewhere in between. Decide whether to spend more on tripod or not. [I have a Manfrotto tripod head on a solid no name base. With a 500mm lens with 1.7x teleconverter [somewhat extreme case] it takes more than 5 seconds to settle when "tapped".

Comment: Would you pick a 35mm 1.8 or a 50mm 1.4?

Comment: The 35 is very versatile and great quality for the price. Seeing as you plan on getting the longer lens too it would be a valid choice.